# Padding on image overlay CSS

Tags: html, css, overlay

I want to create an overlay on a image but it needs to have a 20px inset. The only problem is I'm using width: 100% and height: 100% on the overlay so a 20px padding wasn't working. The thing I tried next was the following:

```
<div class="projectwrapper">
<div class="projectOverlayInset">
    <div class="projectOverlay"></div>
</div>
    <img class="projectImage" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/Tower_Bridge_opening_at_night_for_a_ferry.jpg" style="display:block" />
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.projectwrapper {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 75%;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

.projectwrapper img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

img {
max-width: 100%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border: 0;
}

.projectOverlay {
position: absolute;
z-index: 20;
width: 100%;
height:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.projectOverlayInset {
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 20px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0ydexva7/2/)

But I just can't get it to work. Even not with the box-sizing trick.

I think this is a really easy question haha.

Thanks in Advance.

Greets,

Wouter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `absolute` positioning to the container `projectOverlayInset` from the overlay, the padding doesn't work for you because the overlay was out of the flow with the `absolute`:

```css
.projectwrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 75%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.projectwrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 0;
}
.projectOverlay {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.projectOverlayInset {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="projectwrapper">
  <div class="projectOverlayInset">
    <div class="projectOverlay"></div>
  </div>
  <img class="projectImage" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/Tower_Bridge_opening_at_night_for_a_ferry.jpg" style="display:block" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks hahaa, knew I was messing up somewhere. Did the trick!

Comment: @Wouter125 glad to help the point is you can understand why your code has the right properties but wasn't working :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the requirement correctly, you do not need the `inset` div at all.

The overlay can be positioned and the dimensions adjusted using `calc` :_

```css
.projectwrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 75%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.projectwrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 0;
}
.projectOverlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="projectwrapper">
  <div class="projectOverlay"></div>
  <img class="projectImage" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/Tower_Bridge_opening_at_night_for_a_ferry.jpg" style="display:block" />
</div>
```